# Google Playstore is showing app as incompatible

Tags: android, google-play

My app is showing incompatible on 
Device Itel-1409
Android Ver : 5.1
Google Play-store Showing
"Your device isn't compatible with this version"
But for other android 5.1 version devices app is available from playstore

My app manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Uses-Features used in app
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.gps"
    android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `aapt dump badging *.apk`? Perhaps it's due to some other restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<uses feature--->` use `<uses_permission-->` to use the hardware parts.

Comment: That's not true, `targetSdkVersion` is *not* `maxSdkVersion`.